# How to switch views fluidly in an Access data sheet?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have a data sheet in my form. There's a check mark that I use to update the view of the data sheet from one view to another.

I do it easily by setting the `SourceObject` of the data sheet to one of 2 views. The problem is, it's not very fluid. In other words, switching between 2 views, there's a delay in time where the data sheet is white before it loads to the other view.

Is there any way to make switching the views in the data sheet appear more fluidly, without that blank sheet appear before the next view is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps

```
DoCmd.Hourglass true     
Me.Painting = False   
.... 
.... change SourceObject
.... 
Me.Painting = True
DoCmd.HourGlass false
```